# interrupt a blocked thread in RMI call

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

Consider the following case:

```
main() {
    ClassA insA = new ClassA();
    insA.run();
}

ClassA.run() {
    for(;;) {
        RMI.call();
        blahblah();
    }
}
```

`RMI.call()` is an RMI function which blocks the thread using `Semaphore.acquire()` till something (in another thread) happens.

The question is: How can I safely kill all the threads?

defining a `stop()` function in `ClassA` like below:

```
stop() {
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
```

and calling it from outside (e.g. `main()`)will NOT interrupt the RMI call thread.

How can I interrupt the original thread, so I can exit the code properly?
Or any other way the exit safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this library: http://java.net/projects/interruptiblermi.
Thread#interrupt() will not help.

Comment: The java.net site has closed. Most Open Source projects previously hosted on java.net have been relocated.